# How to draw this in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, path

How to draw this in flutter using custom paint
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPNfW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly I don't think there is a way to exactly draw that shape in one go.
There are multiple libraries that support creating shapes in flutters, but yours is a very specific and nontrivial one.

I think this post may help you: https://medium.com/devmins/flutter-custom-paint-tutorial-draw-a-custom-shape-path-in-flutter-afbbf0202941. -> cred: Ravi Shankar Singh